# 'setup.py test' egg install location?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have all the eggs my project requires pre-downloaded in a directory, and I would like setuptools to *only* install packages from that directory.

In my `setup.cfg` I have:

```
[easy_install]
allow_hosts = None
find_links = ../../setup
```

I run `python setup.py develop` and it finds and installs all the packages correctly.

For testing, I have an additional requirement, specified in `setup.py`.

```
tests_require=["pinocchio==0.2"],
```

This egg also resides locally in the `../../setup` directory.

I run `python setup.py test` and it sees the dependency and finds the egg in `../../setup` just fine.  However, the egg gets installed to my **current** directory instead of the `site-packages` directory with the rest of the eggs.

I've tried specifying the `install-dir` both in `setup.cfg` and on the command line and neither seemed to work for the `tests` command.

I could just add the dependency to the `install_requires` section, but I'd like to keep what is required for installation and tests separate if possible.

How can I keep the dependency in the `tests_require` section, but have it installed to the `site-packages` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at the source code (setuptools/command/tests.py), it doesn't look like setup.py test is not supposed to install anything by design (it is testing, so why put anything in site-packages?).  It uses fetch_build_egg (setuptools/dist.py) to get the eggs, which actually does a local easy_install.  I suspect you can't trivially make test do what you want.

Notes/ideas:
My experience with setuptools is that it there are bugs in it and undocumented behavior.  (One especially nasty trip-up I found was that it wouldn't enter softlinked directories, when distutils would).

I'd recommend either A) not doing this. :), B) manually installing the file by calling easy_install package.  or C) looking into the setuptools system and maybe adding your own command.  It isn't too difficult to understand, and knowing it will help a lot when you get future setuptools hick-ups.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not going to bother fighting setuptools, and do either A) or B) as you recommended.